# Redireccionar errores a diferentes vistas en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Como podría loggear los diferentes tipos de errores en ASP MVC 5, de igual forma enviarlos a una pantalla o vista de error 500 , 404, etc.

De igual forma como se podrian loguear?

Comment: Me da la impresión que mucha de la idea de tu planteamiento te la quedaste. Da más detalles y agrega lo que has hecho (código) y en obstáculo que estas enfrentando. Respecto a los errores mira en https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para redireccionar a una pagina de errores personalizada utilizas modificas tu web.config debajo de 'system.web' agregas 'customeErrors'; algo como lo siguiente:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.html"/>
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="500.html"/>
</customErrors>
```

Para mas información aquí te dejo un link

http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages